# jquery load callback fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I have this code.

```
function loadBottom(dockitemid)
{
    var itemno = dockitemid.substring(3,4);
    var adres = pages[itemno - 1];

    $("#BottomLoader").fadeIn(300);

    $("#Bottom").load(adres,function(){$("#BottomLoader").fadeOut(800);});
}
```

The problem is it only works for the first time. Once the #Bottom div is loaded with some HTML, the load function still works but does not show the progress div (named #BottomLoader) anymore. Why is this happening?

thx in advance

Comment: its at techlipse.net/test/evemlak

Answer (score 1):

The *BottomLoader* div, is nested inside the *Bottom* div, with [jQuery.load](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load) you are replacing the innerHTML of *Bottom* div, so after the first execution, that div will no longer exist.

I recommend you take out the BottomLoader element:

```
<div id="Bottom">
<!-- This will be replaced by $.load -->                    
</div>
<div id="BottomLoader"></div>
```